# Problems converting enabled/disabled Command-Buttons to visible/invisible

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, icommand

i'm new to UWP/XAML and i already found a few articles regarding this topic but in my case the solution only workes once. Unfortunatelly i'm not allowed to post screenshots, so will try to explain it.
I have two buttons which clock-in/clock-out workers. Both are bound to a command object. If there is no worker "logged in" both buttons are disabled. If there is a worker and he's not clocked-in, the ClockInButton is enabled and the ClockOutButton is disabled and vice versa. This works like a charm!

```
<Button x:Name="ClockInButton" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClockInCommand, Mode=OneWay}" ...></Button>
<Button x:Name="ClockOutButton" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClockOutCommand, Mode=OneWay}...>"</Button>
```

If the ViewModel changes the CanExecuteChanged-Event is raised and the buttons are updated correctly.
Now i want not just enable/disable the buttons but set them visible/invisible so we can display them on the same spot which saves us some space (we have only 23" devices on shopfloor). So i added this to both of my buttons.

```
Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsWorkerClockedIn, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

And this is my converter code (thanks to AlexDrenea for the hints):

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        bool enabled = (bool)value;

        if (enabled)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This works correctly the time i start the app. There is no worker "logged-in" so no button is visible. But they stay invisible if a worker logs in :-(. All events are (now) raised correctly. 
Do i have to write my own "code-behind" or is there a way to meet the requirements by XAML?

Regards,
Nils

Comment: Edit:
I was wrong about the events. I forgot to raise the PropertyChanged-Event but it still doesn't work. I debugged the converter an now it's called every time the property changes. I suspect the visibility is set before the Command-Binding enables one of the buttons. In both cases the bool "enabled" inside the converter is "false".

Comment: Is it because `Mode=OneWay`?

Comment: Hmm i think "One way" is ok. The model updates the button but not backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was blind (at least). The buttons visibility are both bound to the same property so they always are *both* visible or *both* invisible. 
So the idea works if implemented correctly. I'm sorry for any inconvenience caused :-(